# Is it possible to generate Dalvik Bytecode by Rad Studio XE6

Tags: android, delphi, dalvik

It is mentioned [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) that Apps developed by Rad Studio XE are not compatible with all of mobile devices because of directly generating machin-code instead of compiling to Dalvik-Bytecode.

Could anybody please help me if there is any way to compile android projects developed by Rad Studio XE6 into Dalvik bytecode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is mentioned here that Apps developed by Rad Studio XE are not compatible with all of mobile devices because of directly generating machin-code instead of compiling to Dalvik-Bytecode.

That is correct, and that is big problem for Android development because a lot of Android devices use CPU architectures that Embarcadero's Android compilers does not support yet.  Although support for Intel mobile CPUs is on the [current roadmap](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/rad-studio-2015-roadmap).

> Could anybody please help me if there is any way to compile android projects developed by Rad Studio XE6 into Dalvik bytecode?

There is no way to do that with Delphi/C++Builder/RADStudio.  They produce native-CPU machine code only.

FreePascal, on the other hand, has an option to compile Pascal code to Dalvik bytecode:

[FPC JVM](http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_JVM)